# How to keep left color as is using color-stop in css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hope there will be someone to help me.

Basically I'm working on creating custom control from my videos, which currently I'm in the portion of creating track bar which I am using html `type="range"` for that, Now I need to specify the range color based on video duration that has been watched, buffered and is left.

Before mentioning my problem here is my code:

```
vid.addEventListener('progress', function() {
    var val = loadPercentage;
    $('<style>.vidskb_r::-webkit-slider-runnable-track{background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top,color-stop(' + val + ', #fff), color-stop(' + val + ', rgba(0,0,0,0)));}</style>').appendTo('head');
});

$('.pofvv').on("timeupdate",function () {
    var val = ($('.vidskb_r').val() - $('.vidskb_r').attr('min')) / ($('.vidskb_r').attr('max') - $('.vidskb_r').attr('min'));
    $('<style>.vidskb_r::-webkit-slider-runnable-track{background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top,color-stop(' + val + ', #ff7e20), color-stop(' + val + ', rgba(0,0,0,0)));}</style>').appendTo('head');
});
```

The problem is that when it get to progress handler it doesn't shows video duration that is buffered or it shows the buffered duration but does not show the video duration that has been watched.

[This is what I mean](https://s15.postimg.org/xn0i63g97/range_2.png)

Regards

Comment: Your styling might be impaired by the use of the `input` element and webkit pseudo-selectors; CSS often won't always allow fine-grain control over the appearance of form fields. You might want to check out the HTML5 [`progress`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress) element, and this [tutorial on the topic](https://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/).

Comment: @gyre because with `progress` element doesn't give you most of abilities that a range element does, such as: mouse click on a specific portion of range box, jumping to a specific position of the video, there is no thumb on `progress` element and so and so forth. although it could all be done but it is not that simple as to use a range and to design it the way you want.